# PHP get image from download.aspx link

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, ftp

I want to achieve the following:
Get the image from a link, which is always something like the following:

```
https:// ----- /download.aspx?AttachmentType=1001&AttachmentId=c183866d-5fea-e411-9439-00155d011304&CRMWRPCToken=DrGw9N%2bVEeSUOAAVXQETBKgIhPRR8QqL68%2bsPxj1c1zwXvEnxVp9qf8oSKBxujEc&CRMWRPCTokenTimeStamp=635664318841108553
```

and copy it to my FTP server.

I already tested another URL and the code is working like a charm.
But when I try to upload the image with this link, there is just a "file" called `"igyyD3nAjz&CRMWRPCTokenTimeStamp=635664974074974045"` on my FTP server.

Do you know how I can extract the image from this link(s)?

Comment: Have you actually tried something?

Comment: Hi, what should I have tried? I know that it is working, but not with these links.. I am searching already at google if it is possible to extract the "real" image link

Comment: To do something? Like to write a code? Do you have any code snippet for us?

Comment: Well, here my pastebin from the php code http://pastebin.com/trNhX5ME
And here the javascript code, which gets the image link (MS Dynamics CRM 2013): http://pastebin.com/WZq14xDk

Comment: or is it possible to download the image with cURL? I can open the link manually and download the image.

Comment: I tried it with cURL SSLVERIFYPEER false, but it does not work. But the image file (when I create one) says "Object moved to.." now. And also I cannot read the extension and basename from the link.

Comment: FYI: I could reproduce the problem with a gmail image link ("Moved temporarily").. but I still don't know what I can do :(

Comment: Tried to improve layout

Comment: Hey guys
Still no chance to save the picture from the link:

http://crm/CRM/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx?AttachmentType=1001&AttachmentId=7a1ad0be-c8f3-e411-9439-00155d011304&CRMWRPCToken=GGGwOvcoEeSUOQAVXQETBGSO6c00pJ%2bAsLf2Yleexj0taZeu9pJocygs6r8ZkJyg&CRMWRPCTokenTimeStamp=635676144338615142

How can I extract this image with PHP / Javascript? My Code: http://pastebin.com/E7sxNaBL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it!

Now my image is on my ftp server (after extracting it from the database with base64 encoding).

But there is another problem:

I cannot use the success callback of a javascript ajax procedure (alert does not work?).

I echoed some text back from the php file and my javascript does not alert it.

The javascript ajax script looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://crm/ftpupload.php",
      data: {'aid':aid},
      success: function(data) {
         alert(data); //this alert does not show!
      }
   });
```

The echo in the php file looks like this:

```
//ftp check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "ERROR: FTP connection to $ftp_server with user $ftp_user_name has failed!";
    exit;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I fixed it, cross-scripting is restricted so I had to change the path of the php file in the ajax procedure. Now everything is working!